# fetch API error when requesting a json file that I created elsewhere

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

Just starting with asynchronous JavaScript and I'm stuck at understanding something. The thing is when I request or fetch for a normal URL endpoint like "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" it works completely fine, and when I fetch for an existing json file in a relative path, it logs an error:

**Fetch API cannot load file:///D:/Programming/First%20website/work.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.**

here is the code

```
fetch('work.json').then(response =>{
    console.log('promise delivered', response);
    return response.json();
})
.then(data =>{
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(err =>{
    console.log('promise falied, sorry', err)
});
```

any explanation?

Comment: Fetch function takes url not the file name. 
You can use any frameworks like node or express to do so.

Comment: You won't get the server-generated headers when using a file:// - so the trick is to serve the file from the web server.

Answer (score 0):

It supports `fetch` not work on `file` protocol.

Try setting up a local server to serve the `work.json`. You can use a npm package like [http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server) for that. Simple install the package globally and run `http-server .`. You can then access the JSON file via http://localhost:8080/work.json. Then you can point to this URL in `fetch('http://localhost:8080/work.json')

[image]